# How to eliminate white space between element positioned with display:inline-block?

Tags: html, css

I need to display three boxes in line consecutively, using the following code I get always a "gap" of few pixel between them.

I would like to know:

- How to have the box, one after another, no space? I know I can add some minus pixel but I am looking for a more consolidate solution
- Why this happen? Can I re-setter help to solve this problem?
- Do you know any other better alternative?

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box
}
.box {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
#a, #b, #c {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="a" class="box"></div>
    <div id="b" class="box"></div>
    <div id="c" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There were three or four techniques with setting `font-size: 0` on parent, using comment blocks between the inline block elements, using negative margins etc. I am sure there was an existing question.

Comment: Related: http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

Comment: Related: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Comment: I solved this issue using display: flex; on the parent container, example here https://jsfiddle.net/oc9vpx95/ this works fine as I am targeting recent browser with support of css3

Answer (score 0):

Yep `font-size: 0px` to the parent and `vertical-align: top`.